# Remote EJB on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 in Azure

Tags: java, glassfish, corba

I have two very simple EAR files.  One ear exposes a remote stateless ejb (called server.ear) and the other ear is a web module plus a local ejb that lookups the remote ejb bean (client.ear). Via @PostContstruct.

They both are deployed to different instances on Glassfish 3.1.2.2 running Java 7 in all environments.

It works perfectly fine in my container environment on my local machine.  I have two different instances (JVMs) and I'm able to successfully call the remote ejb method from client.ear.  No problems everything works great.

However, when I deploy this to our Azure environment I'm getting this exception:

> Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'com.wk.Hello' in SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=zuse1dldsap01.wkrainier.com, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to acquire SerialContextProvider for SerialContext[myEnv={org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort=3700, java.naming.factory.initial=com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialInitContextFactory, org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost=zuse1dldsap01.wkrainier.com, java.naming.factory.state=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.JNDIStateFactoryImpl, java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=com.sun.enterprise.naming} [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
>   org.omg.CORBA.NO_PERMISSION:   vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No
>       at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecServerRequestInterceptor.handle_null_service_context(SecServerRequestInterceptor.java:421)
>       at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.security.SecServerRequestInterceptor.receive_request(SecServerRequestInterceptor.java:443)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.InterceptorInvoker.invokeServerInterceptorIntermediatePoint(InterceptorInvoker.java:612)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.interceptors.PIHandlerImpl.invokeServerPIIntermediatePoint(PIHandlerImpl.java:612)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.getServantWithPI(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:333)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.java:196)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1624)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:1486)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:990)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(RequestMessage_1_2.java:214)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:742)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.dispatch(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:539)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.doWork(CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.java:2324)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(ThreadPoolImpl.java:497)
>       at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(ThreadPoolImpl.java:540)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]]

I tried to research this issue without any real help. I was wondering if someone came across this issue and what kind of black magic do I need to get this working?  Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm hitting this issue: https://github.com/javaee/glassfish-corba/issues/13

After removing the SSL stuff under the orb-1 from the domain xml and restarting the instances everything works.  Now I just have to remember never to open the ORB Listener tab in GUI every again!